# A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The configure I used has AdministrationAccess

the bucket has following policy configured:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "myPolicy",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

In grantee:

Everyone    with all four operations

I can not imagine a bucket more open than that, why do I still get the error

```
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Comment: Why have you specified the bucket name twice in the Resource?

Comment: @error2007s one is for the bucket itself, the other is for the bucket's content.

Answer (score 4):

Use this policy it will work for full access to the bucket.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET-NAME"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: bucket policy editor gives me the following error "Missing required field Principal - undefined"

Comment: What bucket policy editor? It is a valid policy check this screenshot I am also using that policy in my AWS account http://imgur.com/VzDfZNc

Comment: the bucket policy editor through aws console management. It is a valid IAM policy, is that a valid  s3 bucket policy ? my IAM role has the highest possible access which is Administrator

Comment: Did you try applying that policy by changing the bucket name to your bucket name and check if you are getting the access denied error? Also the above policy is for S3 "Resource": "arn:aws:s3" and why dis you mention the name of bucket twice in your policy?

Comment: yes. I have changed the example-bucket-name to my bucket name. And the error still happens. "why dis you mention the name of bucket twice in your policy?" - I have also no idea, i guess one is for the bucket itself, the other is for objects in the bucket

Answer (score 2):

According to [AWS S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html) examples the specified tresource URI should be a string, not an array. As long as it's not a wildcard.

```
"Resource": [
    "*"
]
```

or

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
```

**Dont forget the trailing wildcard** when you specify your URI.